# setting up a ksoap request

Tags: android, ksoap2

I am using Ksoap from Android to access a .net web service.

The wsdl is formatted like this

```
 <filter>
 <DateFrom> Date1 </DateFrom>
 <DateTo>   Date2 </DateTo>
 </filter>
```

I use addProperty("DateFrom", date1) same for DateTo.
How do I tell ksoap about filter.

The service has a helloword that I can access correctly. When I try the dateservice, ksoap replies with an error: 
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create soap object and inside the soap object you can create/add the property.

> `SoapObject filtertSoapObject = new SoapObject(Util.NAMESPACE, "Filter");
>   filtertSoapObject.addProperty("DateForm", date1);
>   request.addProperty("Filter", filterSoapObject);`

It should work.